# how to work timer in background

Tags: c#

i can run timer but it is hanging , when i run background i need timer to be run in background.
can anyone say me how to run timer in background.
My timer code is

```
        btnIntraday.Enabled = false;
        btnStartBackfill.Enabled = false;
        btnStop.Enabled = true;

        if (btnIntraday.Text == "Intraday")
        {
            timerIntraday.Interval = 5000;
            timerIntraday.Enabled = true;
            btnIntraday.Text = "Updating..";
        }
        else if (btnIntraday.Text == "Updating..")
        {
            timerIntraday.Enabled = false;
            btnIntraday.Text = "Intraday";
        }
```

and my background code is

```
        btnIntraday.Enabled = false;
        btnStartBackfill.Enabled = false;
        btnStop.Enabled = true;

        txtInterval.Text = ddTimeInterval.Value.ToString();
        int inter = (int.Parse(txtInterval.Text)) * multiplyingFactorBackfill;

        try
        {
            bgBackfillDCX.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

can anyone please say me how to run timer in background.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I ask what that code does ? how do you call RunWorkerAsync() by itself (recursive it) ?

Answer (score 2):

You may use a [BackgroundWorker](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker).

Handle the [BackgroundWorker.DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx) to run your timer.

Handle the [BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) to handle timing events.

Handle the [BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) to stop the timer.

Comment: i can run in background but its not auto running

Comment: @voipservicesolution: What do you mean !??

Comment: i need to run the application continuosly without hanging .is there any way to run continuosly in background

Comment: @voipservicesolution: Do you have a problem using BackgroundWorker?

Comment: this is my background code btnIntraday.Enabled = false;         btnStartBackfill.Enabled = false;         btnStop.Enabled = true;          txtInterval.Text = ddTimeInterval.Value.ToString();         int inter = (int.Parse(txtInterval.Text)) * multiplyingFactorBackfill;          try         {             bgBackfillDCX.RunWorkerAsync();         }         catch (Exception ex)         {          }     but it doesnot run continously in timer it run continuosly but it hangs

Comment: @voipservicesolution: Can you please add the code to your question.

Comment: application is running but its now not running continuosly

Comment: @voipservicesolution: What is the thing that is not running continuously ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are saying is that you want to set off the background code then have IT periodically do some work. If so you need a timer in the *background* code not the front end. Which means using a different timer class - in System.Timers, IIRC.  [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If You insist on having the timer working at the front end (though I don't recommend it, I can understand it is easier in some scenarios), there is a way (*note: I presume Windows Forms are used*):

In the following code, there is:

- a timer referring to an instance of System.Windows.Forms.Timer object
- a notifyIcon referring to an instance System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon object
- MainWindow_Resize method associated with Resize event of the form
- notifyIcon_Click method associated with Click event of the notifyIcon

The resize method if-block is executed when user minimizes form (form is not visible anywhere in desktop and setting ShowInTaskBar to false hides it from task bar as well, so it is effectively hidden).

```
private void MainWindow_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        notifyIcon.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

When user clicks notification icon, the form's window is restored to its former size and position and the form is brought to user

```
private void notifyIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    notifyIcon.Visible = false;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
    this.BringToFront();
    this.Activate();
}
```